# Webscraping : Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape the indeed website as part of a project work. I encountered 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' while trying to obtain the summary of the job post.

Anyone got a solution ?

```
def extract(page):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://ae.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=dubai&start={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    div = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
    for item in div:
        title = item.find('a').text.strip()
        company = item.find('span', class_ = 'company').text.strip()
        summary = item.find(name='div',attrs={'class':'summary'}).text.strip()
        
        jobs = {'title': title,
               'company': company,
               'summary': summary}
        joblist.append(jobs)
    return
joblist = []
c = extract(10)
transform(c)
print(joblist)
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-eefd76c3693a> in <module>
     24 joblist = []
     25 c = extract(10)
---> 26 transform(c)
     27 print(joblist)

<ipython-input-65-eefd76c3693a> in transform(soup)
     11         title = item.find('a').text.strip()
     12         company = item.find('span', class_ = 'company').text.strip()
---> 13         summary = item.find(name='div',attrs={'class':'summary'}).text.strip()
     14 #         summary = item.find(name='li',attrs={'style':'margin-bottom:0px;'}).text
     15 #         for sum in summary:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Well, are you expecting `item.find(name='div',attrs={'class':'summary'})` to always return something? What if there is no summary?

Comment: item not find div that class=summary,so it return NoneType object

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for that question. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the code with a try, except block. It worked fine.

```
try:
    summary = item.find(name='div',attrs={'class':'summary'}).text.strip()
except:
    summary = 'None'
```